# formula to calculate possible random numbers

Tags: php, javascript, random, probability

I am web developer. I need to create a function to get the posible random number for given length of string. Please give the formula for that.

ex:-

```
1 digit = 10 (0,1,2,3,......9)
2 digit = (00,01,02,...11,12,13,...)
```

please help me ! Thanks

Comment: Oh really, if anybody has privilege to move this question to stackoverflow . please do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest possible value that uses $n$ decimal digits is zero (assuming you don't allow negative numbers, which I assume you don't) and the largest is $99\dots 9$, where there are $n$ $9$s. A shorter way of writing that number is $10^n - 1$, so your function should return a list of every number from $0$ to $10^n - 1$.

In many programming languages this is trivial to write:

In Python 2.7:

```
def sample(n):
    return range(10**n)
```

In R:

```
sample <- function(n) {
    return(seq(0, 10^n-1))
}
```

Comment: so you mean 2 digit has 99 random possibilities.

Comment: There are 100 possibilities if you include zero, just like there are 10 possibilities for a 1 digit number if you include zero. In general there are $10^n$ possibilities for an $n$ digit number, if you include zero.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's what you are looking for, but if $U$ is a uniform$(0,1)$ random variable, then
$X := \left\lfloor {10^n U} \right\rfloor$, where $\left\lfloor  \cdot  \right\rfloor $ is the floor function, has a discrete uniform distribution on $\{0,1,\ldots,10^n - 1\}$; that is, ${\rm P}(X = k) = \frac{1}{{10^n }}$, for any $k \in \{0,1,\ldots,10^n-1\}$. So the formula is $f(n)=\left\lfloor {10^n U} \right\rfloor$.

Comment: So, for example, $f(2)$ returns a uniform random value in $\{0,1,\ldots,99\}$.

Comment: I don't understand anything expect first line. I feeling shame as being engineer.